# Retarget blocks submitted to dispatch queue

Tags: ios, c, grand-central-dispatch

I have serial dispatch queue `Q` (with another serial queue `T` as a target) and few blocks already submitted via `dispatch_async(Q, block)`. Is there a way to retarget pending blocks to another queue `A`?

My simple test shows that `Q` forwards blocks to `T` as soon as possible, thus setting new target has no effect:

```
#define print(f, ...) printf(f "\n", ##__VA_ARGS__)

dispatch_queue_t Q = dispatch_queue_create("Q", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
dispatch_queue_t T = dispatch_queue_create("T", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
dispatch_queue_t A = dispatch_queue_create("A", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);

dispatch_set_target_queue(Q, T);

dispatch_async(T, ^{ print("T sleeping"); sleep(2); print("T ready"); });
dispatch_async(A, ^{ print("A sleeping"); sleep(5); print("A ready"); });

dispatch_async(Q, ^{
    print("block 1");
    dispatch_set_target_queue(Q, A); // no effect!
});
dispatch_async(Q, ^{ print("block 2"); });
dispatch_async(Q, ^{ print("block 3"); });
dispatch_async(Q, ^{ print("block 4"); });
```

Output:

```
A sleeping
T sleeping
(wait 2 seconds)
T ready
block 1
block 2
block 3
block 4
(wait 3 seconds)
A ready
```

As you can see, blocks 2-4 were pinned to `T` even though manual states:

> The new target queue setting will take effect between block executions on the object, but not in the middle of any existing block executions (non-preemptive).

It is unclear to me if that only applies to dispatch sources, or "existing" means already submitted (even not yet executed) blocks, but anyway, thing doesn't happen for my serial queue.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: In reference to `dispatch_set_target_queue`, the docs say "Changing a dispatch source’s queue is an asynchronous operation and the dispatch source does its best to make the change as quickly as possible. If an event handler is already queued and waiting to be processed, it executes on the previous queue. However, other events arriving around the time you make the change could be processed on either queue." Admittedly, that's about sources, but the behavior you describe seems analogous.

Comment: BTW, besides being unwieldy, the problem with the second code snippet is that the dispatched block will wait in one queue and will only be redirected to the other queue when it's done waiting in the first queue, at which point it's added to the end of that other queue. This is both inefficient and obtuse. I can imagine other models, but it depends upon what the functional intent here is. Maybe you can step back and describe a practical problem that you're trying to solve here and we might be able to suggest better approaches.

Comment: @Rob Thanks for pointing that out! Blocks may even appear intermixed in a race between `T` and original submitter-thread. I think I should put blocks in a regular atomic queue and pick from there when it is time. Bigger picture is not so big: I have concurrent processes that communicate via "rpc-channels". Channel can be passed through other channel and from that time calls should go to new owner (old owner invalidates his handle).

Comment: @Rob I think I found correct solution (posted as answer), thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after studying a bit I came up with the following solution. It is based on custom dispatch source, and I think it is the only way to submit blocks just-in-time.

BlockSource.h:

```
dispatch_source_t dispatch_block_source_create(dispatch_queue_t queue);
void dispatch_block_source_add_block(dispatch_source_t source, dispatch_block_t block);
```

BlockSource.c:

```
struct context {
    CFMutableArrayRef array;
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    dispatch_source_t source;
};

static void
s_event(struct context *context)
{
    dispatch_block_t block;
    CFIndex pending;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&context->mutex); {
        block = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(context->array, 0);
        CFArrayRemoveValueAtIndex(context->array, 0);
        pending = CFArrayGetCount(context->array);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&context->mutex);

    block();
    Block_release(block);

    if (pending)
        dispatch_source_merge_data(context->source, 1);
}

static void
s_cancel(struct context *context)
{
    CFIndex count = CFArrayGetCount(context->array);
    for (CFIndex i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        dispatch_block_t block = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(context->array, i);
        Block_release(block);
    }
    CFRelease(context->array);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&context->mutex);
    print("canceled");
}

dispatch_source_t
dispatch_block_source_create(dispatch_queue_t queue)
{
    dispatch_source_t source = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_DATA_OR, 0, 0, queue);

    struct context *context = calloc(1, sizeof(*context));
    context->array = CFArrayCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&context->mutex, NULL);
    context->source = source;

    dispatch_set_context(source, context);
    dispatch_source_set_event_handler_f(source, (dispatch_function_t)s_event);
    dispatch_source_set_cancel_handler_f(source, (dispatch_function_t)s_cancel);
    dispatch_set_finalizer_f(source, (dispatch_function_t)free);

    return source;
}

void
dispatch_block_source_add_block(dispatch_source_t source, dispatch_block_t block)
{
    struct context *context = dispatch_get_context(source);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&context->mutex); {
        CFArrayAppendValue(context->array, Block_copy(block));
        dispatch_source_merge_data(context->source, 1);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&context->mutex);
}
```

And the test case:

```
dispatch_queue_t T = dispatch_queue_create("T", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
dispatch_queue_t A = dispatch_queue_create("A", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);

static int queue_name_key;
dispatch_queue_set_specific(T, &queue_name_key, "T", NULL);
dispatch_queue_set_specific(A, &queue_name_key, "A", NULL);

dispatch_source_t source = dispatch_block_source_create(T);
dispatch_resume(source);

for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    dispatch_block_source_add_block(source, ^{
        print("block %d on queue %s", i, dispatch_get_specific(&queue_name_key));
        sleep(1);

        if (i == 2) {
            dispatch_set_target_queue(source, A);
        }
        else if (i == 5) {
            dispatch_source_cancel(source);
            dispatch_release(source);
        }
    });
}
```

Output:

```
block 1 on queue T
block 2 on queue T
block 3 on queue A
block 4 on queue A
block 5 on queue A
canceled
```

At least now it follows dispatch source's scheme after `dispatch_set_target_queue()` call. This means that if new target queue is set while inside one of submitted blocks, it is guaranteed that all remaining blocks will go to new queue.

May still contain bugs.